# Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), Could not authenticate you

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, twython

I simply want to post a tweet from my Raspberry Pi and keep getting a 401 error.

-----------------------------------------This is my code-----------------------------------------

```
import sys
from twython import Twython
consumer_key='x'
consumer_secret='x'
access_token='x'
access_token_secret='x'

twitter = Twython(
   consumer_key,
   consumer_secret,
   access_token,
   access_token_secret
)

twitter.update_status(status='Test')
```

----------------------------------------Trace back------------------------------------------------

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Programs/tweetTest.py", line 29, in <module>
    twitter.update_status(status='Test')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twython/endpoints.py", line 123, in update_status
    return self.post('statuses/update', params=params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twython/api.py", line 274, in post
    return self.request(endpoint, 'POST', params=params, version=version)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twython/api.py", line 264, in request
    api_call=url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twython/api.py", line 199, in _request
    retry_after=response.headers.get('X-Rate-Limit-Reset'))
twython.exceptions.TwythonAuthError: Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), Could not authenticate you
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it appears you have misspelled 'consumer_secret' in your Twython instance: `concumer_secret`.

Secondly, if you have a desktop app (which I assume you have since this is tagged "raspberry-pi") it looks like you don't need to provide access tokens, just the 'APP_KEY' and 'APP_SECRET'. If you are using the oauth tokens, you might want to provide the code where you are receiving those in case that is the source of the problem.

Comment: yes, the "concumer_secret" was a typo when I transferred my code from the pi to my main computer. I took out the acess_tokens portion and I am still receiving the same error. 

I currently don't have code asking for oauth tokens. Is this something that I need to do?